# Call a component method from other component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a list of playlists shown on my page. This list is provided by an external API. Each playlist has a delete button, and i'm trying to make this button work.

The delete in the API works fine, as the playlist gets removed from the API. Now the missing part, is to remove the playlist from my view.

I have a component named "Playlists.vue", containing this code :

```
<div class="playlists" v-if="playlists">
        <playlist v-for="playlist in playlists"
                  v-bind:key="playlist.id"
                  v-bind:playlist="playlist">
        </playlist>
        <span v-if="playlists.length === 0">No playlist found</span>
</div>
```

In the Playlists.vue file, a fetchData function provide the data :

```
 methods: {
      async fetchData() {
        const playlists = await api.getAllPlaylists();
      }
    }
```

Then i have another component to display a single playlist, Playlist.vue :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <textarea v-model="playlist.name" v-on:blur="updatePlaylist"></textarea> 
      <button v-on:click="deletePlaylist(playlist.id)">Delete</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Si i tried to re call the fetchData function after every delete, to update the playlists variable to get the updated list after delete. So i started by importing the component Playlists.js this way :

```
 import playlists from './Playlists';
```

And then i called the fetchData function in my delete function :

```
deletePlaylist(id) {
        playlist.deletePlaylist(id);
        playlists.fetchData();
},
```

But it does not work unfortunately, i always get this error :

> Uncaught TypeError:
>   **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__Playlists**.a.fetchData is not a function

I tried other solutions, but i can't call methods from Playlists.vue in Playlist.vue

Any fix ? or maybe a better solution ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Show the code of `getAllPlaylists`

Comment: ***Components never call each other's methods directly***. You need to emit an event on the component that wants to make the call, and listen to that even in the component where the method is located. This is called loose coupling and a basic principle of component oriented development.

Answer (score 0):

I think a good solution would be to use a Mixin. You can do a global Mixin as follows.

```
Vue.mixin({
  methods: {
     async fetchData() {
       const playlists = await api.getAllPlaylists();
     }
  }
});
```

Put this before your main Vue instance and it will be available to any of your components.

If you don't want it to be available globally define it as below.

```
var fetchData = {
  methods: {
     async fetchData() {
       const playlists = await api.getAllPlaylists();
     }
  }
}
```

Then include it in your component definitions

```
  export default {
     mixins: [fetchData],
     data(){
        //...
     }
  }
```

More on Mixins https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html